# query while working with PDPageNode using pdfBox

Tags: pdfbox

```
 document = PDDocument.load(filePath); 
 System.out.println(" pages count = " + document.getNumberOfPages());
 PDDocumentCatalog docCata = new PDDocumentCatalog(document);
 Map<String,Integer> pmap = document.getPageMap();
 System.out.println("count = "+ pmap.size() ); //This prints count = 562        
 pnode =docCata.getPages();
 kidList = pnode.getKids();
 System.out.println("Size of kidList =" + kidList.size());   //this also prints Size of kidList = 0 

//System.out.println("-------size= "+pnode.getRotation()) //throws null pointer exception
```

Hi I tried working with the above code , however I am not able to get the kids using the pnode.getKids.

The above gives the following output:

```
pages count = 562
count = 562
Size of kidList =0
```

I am not getting why kidList is not getting populated even when the PDF has pages.
Please provide some help in this context.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want to do

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCata = document.getDocumentCatalog();
```

instead of

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCata = new PDDocumentCatalog(document);
```

`getDocumentCatalog()` retrieves the existing document catalog while `new PDDocumentCatalog(document)` creates a new one without any pages.